# How to implement Background Service which continue even if app is removed from recent?

Tags: android, android-service

Want to implement Service which continue even if app is removed from recent, and from that service generate notification for User.
like any news Application, notification for news shows even if app does not run in front end and removed from recent activities in android.

Comment: foreground service

Comment: As i'm new development ,I'd try onTaskRemoved() ,START_STICKY in onStartCommand ,can you please share any example or link from where i can understand easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) and send the notification from server when a news is Updated. You don't need a service. Notification will be arrived when your app is in background. I think you are searching for Push Notification. Check out this tutorial for Everything about firebase offically by GOOGLE.

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/index.html

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day..@Avinash Verma

Comment: No Problem. In that tutorial you will find every tutorial of Firebase. Firebase has many components like monetize, cloud,real time for chatting and more. don't get confuse, just search for what you are need.

Comment: here is the tutorial what you need.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Android Background Service

Check this Link

[Creating a Background Service](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html)